# NopCommerce 4.30 Overriding Register.cshtml

Tags: c#, .net, nopcommerce

i want to override Nop.Web Views (Login,Register).
i'm creating a new plugin and i'm using NopCommerce 4.3.
All the solutions i found are not compatible with 4.3 Version.
Any Help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can use similar solution to solve this problem.
In your RouteProvider.cs

```
public partial class RouteProvider : IRouteProvider
   {
    public void RegisterRoutes(IEndpointRouteBuilder endpointRouteBuilder)
        {
               endpointRouteBuilder.MapControllerRoute("RedirectLogin",
                    "yourController/yourAction",
                    new { controller = "Customer", action = "Register" });
        }
    }
```

I hope this helped